# Google Custom Search results are different than expected

Tags: search

I am using a GCS engine on a site.  I don't want a custom search, just a regular google search with the Adsense linking.  If I use the main google.com site to search for "gallerykunst" the expected result shows up as #1, in the CSE it does not exist at all.

Any ideas!?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2595438/google-custom-search-engine-not-giving-the-expected-search-result as the problem was similar, URL's weren't showing up in the CSE results at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this out:
http://www.google.com/support/customsearch/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=141877

I'm seeing the same thing happen.  It looks like there is some delay when you first set it up, and it's the sort of problem that gets fixed over time (maybe about 20 days?).